# CGRect to UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have this code:

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = mainViewController.scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = mainViewController.scrollView.bounds.size;
```

I want to store the content inside `visibleRect` in a `UIImage`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may work:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(visibleRect.size);
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), visibleRect.origin.x,
    visibleRect.origin.y);
[mainViewController.scrollView.layer 
    renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: renderInContext not found, why?

Comment: It's just a warning, right? I think it will still work - the compiler flakes out on `layer` methods, even though they're there and will work fine.

Comment: I add #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> then it now work, but I have a white rect and not the content of scrollview

Comment: @blackguardian: thanks, you just fixed a warning I was getting from trying to call `setMasksToBounds` on a view's layer (the proper import statement made the warning go away, although the code worked fine with the warning).

Comment: Regarding the white rectangle, I'm not sure `mainViewController.scrollView` is the correct view for this. A `UIScrollView` (which is what I'm guessing your `scrollView` object is) can contain other views (which are then made scrollable within the bounds of the scroll view) - you probably just need to identify which actual view in your object structure contains the image you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a UIImage in the CGRect. You'd do something like the following

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = mainViewController.scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = mainViewController.scrollView.bounds.size;

UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[img setFrame:visibleRect];
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your-img"]];
[[self view] addSubview:img];
[img release];
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to copy what's visible in the CGRect into a UIImage - like taking a screen capture.

Comment: no, I want take the visible rect of my scrollview and save it in an UIImageView or UIImage